# python matplotlib mathtext AMSeuler fonts

Tags: fonts, matplotlib

Is there a way to use AMSeuler fonts in matplotlib graphics?
I already tried with rc('mathtext', fontset='eulermath'), but of course is not working
as that font is not available in matplotlibrc.
That's quite annoying as Computer Modern fonts are not really goodlooking on Palatino fonts used in ClassicThesis style.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution by myself, but not exactly what i was looking for, see
https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz

any other suggestion is welcome